# Taking substring from pathname in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I currently have the following rule in a Makefile:

```
../obj/%.o: %.cpp
         mkdir -p ../obj/$<
         $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -c $< -o $@
         rmdir ../obj/$<
```

It takes a cpp file and builds an object file from it, storing the object file under the obj directory. I have multilpe folder hierarchies and this stores the object files within this heirarchy, e.g:

```
log/internal/log_level.cpp = ../obj/log/internal/log_level.o
```

As is clear i have hacked make to build the required folders under ../obj. Is there a way I can use make, perhaps through patsubst, whereby I could mkdir with the value of $< not including the filename?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a C++ question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `$(<D)`? [Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Automatic-Variables.html).